# How to grant access to an ssh tunnel to access svn but not the shell

Tags: linux, svn, ssh, tunnel

Is there a way to grant access to a user on linux to connect through an ssh tunnel to the svn without granting him access to the shell?

Answer (score 0):

If you use private/public key authentication, thats rather easy. You can specify the commands that a user authenticated with a specific key is able to execute, so he can only execute svn related commands.

Have a look at these:

http://man.he.net/man5/authorized_keys under "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT"

http://www.geekisp.com/faq/content/7/58/en/how-can-i-use-multiple-svn_only-users-over-ssh-without-giving-then-shell-access.html

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/ssh-tricks